# PHP - javascript login form

Tags: javascript, php, html, authentication

I have a problem. I cant echo the message that tells the user that he inputted wrong username or password that it failed to login.

I'm trying to create a message to display but cant somehow. I'm using session, I tried some suggestions from this site but its not working somehow.

Also the pop up is using javascript.

login form

```
<div class="popover"">
    <form action="login.php" name="indexform" method="post">
        <input class = "input1a" type="text" name="uname" placeholder="USERNAME . . . "  autofocus/>
        <br/>
        <input class = "input1a" type="password" name="pword" placeholder="PASSWORD . . . " />
        <br/>
        <center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="LOGIN" /><button type="reset" value="Reset" />RESET</button></center>
    </form>
    <center><a href="#" class="close">Close Window</a></center>
</div>
```

Here's the guest page.

index.php

```
<?php

//Initialize Session
session_start();

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

//$name = $_SESSION['username'];
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
        echo 'Incorrect Username and Password!';
        header('Location: admin.php');
    }
  ?>
```

And here's the admin page after successful login

admin.php

```
<?php
// Inialize session
session_start();

// Check, if username session is NOT set then this page will jump to login page
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    header('Location: index.php');
}
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();

include("config.php");

$login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']) . "') and (password = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pword']) . "')");
// Check username and password match
if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
    // Set username session variable
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['uname'];

    // Jump to secured page
    header('Location: index_admin.php');
} else {

    // Jump to login page

    header('Location: index.php');

}
?>
```

And lastly the javascript for the popup window.

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".button").click(function (e) {
        $(".overlay").css({
            "opacity": "0.4"
        });
        $(".overlay").fadeIn("slow");
        $(".popover").fadeIn(1000);
        $(".popover").show();
        $(".close").click(function (e) {
            $(".popover, .overlay").fadeOut(700);
            /*$(".popover, .overlay").hide();*/
        });
    });
});
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. I'm still new to javascript and php. I wish I can create a pop up message after failed login but I'm still confused with the workaround. :(

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to go if you want to trigger javascript for login form...

1. Create a **service** (in PHP) that checks the authentication credentials and returns JSON response.
2. Submit the form with javascript using an ajax call to the service.
3. Use form submission ajax **callback** to trigger a popup in the event that service returns error.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is in `<div class="popover"">` - there should be only `<div class="popover">`.

And the second problem is, that `header()` will relocate you at the same time you echoes error message. So, error message is written, but due to relocating, it *stays* on original place - and you cannot read it.

So, you need to create intermission phase, where you will have that error message - and from this place you can relocate anywhere on any click.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you want to echo the message in one file but display it in the page where the form is. You can pass the message to another file by following methods:

1. Use ajax where the form is and get response to know if the credentials are valid and display the message.
2. Store the message in a session variable and display it when the other file loads.

Or you can just add the authentication code to the page containing the form and just call back the same page as follows:

**index.php**

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    //Initialize Session
    session_start();

    include("config.php");

    $login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']) . "') and (password = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pword']) . "')");
    // Check username and password match
    if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
        // Set username session variable
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['uname'];
        header('Location: admin.php');
    } else {
        echo 'Incorrect Username and Password!';
    }

}

?>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="popover">
            <form action="index.php" name="indexform" method="post">
                <input class = "input1a" type="text" name="uname" placeholder="USERNAME . . . "  autofocus/>
                <br/>
                <input class = "input1a" type="password" name="pword" placeholder="PASSWORD . . . " />
                <br/>
                <center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="LOGIN" /><button type="reset" value="Reset" />RESET</button></center>
            </form>
            <center><a href="#" class="close">Close Window</a></center>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```